# Collision Detection works only with two objects

Tags: c++, collision-detection, game-physics, physics, sdl-2

I've been trying to write a collision detection program and it's not always detecting a collision. I've found that when I have two objects the collisions work fine when I only have one object detecting the other. For example if I have objects blue and red the program will work fine with `blue->collisionManager(red);` . Since I want to add more objects I'm running a 2d array for now that looks like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    if (arr[i] != arr[j]) {
        arr[i]->collisionManager(arr[j]);
    }
}
arr[i]->checkWall();
```

}

So what I think is going on is that one object is detecting a collision from the other but when the other detects the collision it sort of negates the whole process. My idea is to put a boolean to tell the other object that the first is already in a collision. But I don't know how to implement this boolean in my code. This is my collision manager and detection code

```
    void platform::collisionManager(platform* other) {  
    if (this->checkCollision(other)) {
        this->anglelessCollision(other);
    }
}

bool platform::checkCollision(platform* square)
{
    bool AisToTheRightOfB = this->getLeft() > square->getRight();
    bool AisToTheLeftOfB = this->getRight() < square->getLeft();
    bool AisAboveB = this->getBottom() < square->getTop();
    bool AisBelowB = this->getTop() > square->getBottom();
    return !(AisToTheRightOfB
        || AisToTheLeftOfB
        || AisAboveB
        || AisBelowB);
    
}
```

Comment: [Collision Detection not working sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78105038/collision-detection-not-working-sometimes)

Comment: Regarding _"...but when the other detects the collision it sort of negates the whole process"_ -- can you be more specific about what you mean? Are you doing something like bouncing them off eachother, and your code reflects the objects twice? If you have a look at your two loops, you'll see that you're testing every collision twice because `j` iterates over the whole range. It would make more sense to run the inner loop from `i+1` instead of `0`, since the collision code itself does not care about ordering.

Comment: Note that if you end up in a situation where _three_ (or more) objects collide, things could potentially go haywire. In that case, you may want to use disjoint sets or similar to group items that are part of a simultaneous collision and solve those differently. Based on the nature of your question though, that topic might be too advanced.

Comment: Have you written some unit tests and debugged your project yet? The collision detection code should be a testable (free standing) function independent of the rest of your engine. Side note if you don't need indices use range based for loops.

Comment: @paddy thanks! I'm going to try that out. So what I meant is that both a.collisionManager(b) and b.collisionManger(a) will run at the same time, but the outcome should be the same no matter which one runs so I think that was where I was running into problems

Comment: @paddy I remember what a disjoint set is from my proof writing classes but wouldn't know how to apply it here. I'll look into that as well.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I learned how to use the debug software and that helped me boil it down. But I still have to learn how to write unit tests. I use them to turn in my programs in class in java but I haven't looked into c++

Comment: @paddy That definitely fixed them going through each other. There's still some weirdness like you predicted, but it solved the problem I was working on thanks.

Comment: It is an essential skill to develop (specially for somewhat bigger projects). One framework that's often used is google test : https://google.github.io/googletest/primer.html. The idea is you put the functions under test in a (statically) linkable lib (so move them out of your game.exe project). And then you can link the test  (and game) executable with that lib. You probably also want to learn a bit about dependency inversion/injection (e.g. use interface).